Python PySIde6 QtCore warning in VS code
I am taking my first steps with PySide 6 and i tried some sample code I found in a tutorial. The code works but i get warnings from VS code for the "canvas.fill" line:
import sys
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    canvas = QtGui.QPixmap(400, 300)
    canvas.fill(Qt.red)
    #canvas.fill(Qt.GlobalColor.red)
    #canvas.fill(QtGui.QColor(200,150,0))
    self.label.setPixmap(canvas)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.label)
    self.draw_something()

def draw_something(self):
    canvas = self.label.pixmap()
    painter = QtGui.QPainter(canvas)
    painter.drawLine(10, 10, 300, 200)
    painter.end()
    self.label.setPixmap(canvas)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()

VS Code problem
Autocompletion also does not work properly. When I type Qt. there is no "red" in the list. So why does this work although there seems to be a problem? I found several other examples on the net which are also using the method that is causing the problem for me. Am I missing something?
I found out that the two alternatives below the problem line are working.


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors; 2. Change to Qt.GlobalColor.red.

